# Remove space chars from end of string C++

Tags: c++, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the best way to trim std::string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216823/whats-the-best-way-to-trim-stdstring)

I have a string:

```
std::string foo = "This is a string    "; // 4 spaces at end
```

How would I remove the spaces at the end of the string so that it is:

```
"This is a string" // no spaces at end
```

please note this is an example and not a representation of my code. I do not want to hard code:

```
std::string foo = "This is a string"; //wrong
```

Comment: This is usually known as `trim`, check out for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216823/whats-the-best-way-to-trim-stdstring

Comment: Possible dup: [What's the best way to trim std::string](http://stackoverflow.com/q/216823/725163)

Comment: Spaces (ASCII code 32) are not NULL (ASCII code 0). Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798112/removing-leading-and-trailing-spaces-from-a-string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216823/whats-the-best-way-to-trim-stdstring) you can find a lot of ways to trim the string.

Comment: I wonder why this answer is downvoted...

Comment: I can't speak for the other downvoter, but I downvoted it because, instead of voting to close as a dupe, you tried to reap rep by linking to the other answer. As a 10k user you should have learned enough of SO to know that closing this as a dupe would have been the proper course of action. (For the same reason I thought I wouldn't need to bother to explain myself.)

Answer (score 0):

First off, NULL chars (ASCII code 0) and whitespaces (ASCII code 32) and not the same thing.

You could use `std::string::find_last_not_of` to find the last non-whitespace character, and then use `std::string::resize` to chop off everything that comes after it.

Answer (score -1):

```
string remove_spaces(const string &s)
{
  int last = s.size() - 1;
  while (last >= 0 && s[last] == ' ')
    --last;
  return s.substr(0, last + 1);
}
```