# C++ How to remove \0 char from std::string

Tags: c++, stdstring

What is the correct way to remove the `\0` char´s from a given string.

I´m trying with no success:

```
std::string msg(data); // Data comes from a remote system connected via socket...
msg.erase(std::remove(msg.begin(), msg.end(), '\0'), msg.end());
```

This gives compilation error:

```
error: cannot convert ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >}’ to ‘const char*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int remove(const char*)’
```

`data`comes from a remote system using socket, and contains several pieces of code numbers with `/0` in the middle due to source logic.

Comment: This isn't a good idea, is it? Since C++11, `std::string` is terminated by `'\0'`, so I think this might not be wise.

Comment: I´m receiving a socket data from a remote system that is coming with `\0` chars. That string will be processed in a string comparator logic and later issue  mySql inserts/creates that is thowing several errors due to the `\0` presence on the string. So I need to sanitize the string removing these chars.

Comment: @erip: That '\0' is not part of the data. It's an implementation detail, part of the interface. This would not affect it.

Comment: `argument ‘1’ to ‘int remove(const char*)'` wait what

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Understood.

Comment: The message contains `int remove(const char*)`, which seems like a different overload. Where did that come from?

Comment: Your approach is [correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20326356/how-to-remove-all-the-occurrences-of-a-char-in-c-string), so something else is wrong. Present your testcase.

Comment: msg is `std::string`

Comment: Please provide an [mcve] that gives that error.  The code you have should work.

Comment: Did you `#include <algorithm>`?

Comment: Isn't the base problem that the constructor used here will assume the string ends at the first `'\0'`? [How do you construct a std::string with an embedded null?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164168/how-do-you-construct-a-stdstring-with-an-embedded-null)

Comment: No repro http://ideone.com/mdXvw5

Comment: Perhaps a better approach to construct the string would be using `std::copy_if`.

Comment: `#include <algorithm>` did the trick... Thanks all... erip: Removing the `\0`´s seens not to be affecting the string in latter logic....

Comment: @crashmstr: If you used that particular constructor to create the string then, yes, you'd have a problem. Not this problem though. And you wouldn't use that particular constructor to create the string because that would be stupid.

Comment: Five upvotes for a missing header. smh

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem arises from a missing `#include` directive. Your intention was to call [`std::remove()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) from `<algorithm>`, but you inadvertently called [`std::remove()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/remove) from `<cstdio>`. So with

```
#include <algorithm>
```

it should work.

(IMHO `std::remove(const char*)` should be `std::remove_file(std::string const&)` or at least `std::remove_file(const char*)`.)