# Removing character from string c++

Tags: c++, string, replace

I am trying to remove a specific character from a string but am having difficulties.

Ive tried using replace() and replacing the character with nothing, but the compiler complains about that.

```
string s = "Hello, this is a test";
replace (s.begin(), s.end(), 'l', '');
cout << s;
```

What i would like is for it to find and remove the character 'l' so it outputs "Heo, this is a test".
Unfortunately i don't think replace() is the correct thing to use and am a bit stumped. Have only been learning programming for a couple weeks, so I'm sorry if this is a dumb question. Thanks :)

Comment: See this [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/replace/). It should be `s.replace` instead of `replace`

Comment: Can you show us the error, that you are getting? I am **sure** that it tells **exactly** what's wrong. @sinsuren No, it won't, since `''` is not a valid character.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove all the occurrences of a char in c++ string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20326356/how-to-remove-all-the-occurrences-of-a-char-in-c-string)

Comment: @sinsuren, @GAVD `std::string::replace` doesn't search characters and doesn't replace it with another. It removes one range and inserts another one.

Comment: Are you search answer first you ask here? It's very simply question.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This is pretty staight foward. If you want to replace *Hello* with *Heo* call the function with these parameters `ReplaceWord(str, "Hello", "Heo")`.

Please note that this example is case sensitive so if you use a lowercase h, it will not replace at all, it wont find the word, it has to be a uppercase H.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


void ReplaceWord( std::string& source, const char* WordToFind, const char* WordToReplace );

//program entry point
int main (){

    cout<<""<<endl;

    string str = "Hello, this is a test";

    cout<<"Before replace : "<<endl;
    cout<<str<<endl;
    cout<<""<<endl;

    ReplaceWord(str, "Hello", "Heo");

    cout<<"After replace : "<<endl;
    cout<<str<<endl;

    cout<<""<<endl;

return 0;
}


void ReplaceWord( std::string& source, const char* WordToFind, const char* WordToReplace ){

   size_t LengthOfWordToReplace = strlen(WordToFind);
   size_t replaceLen = strlen(WordToReplace);
   size_t positionToSearchAt = 0;

   //search for the next word 
   while ((positionToSearchAt = source.find(WordToFind, positionToSearchAt)) != std::string::npos)
   {
      //replace the found word with the new word
      source.replace( positionToSearchAt, LengthOfWordToReplace, WordToReplace );

      // move to next position
      positionToSearchAt += replaceLen; 
   }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Hoping that you have added `#include<algorithm>`, the error message should complain about the empty character constant. You have to use `'\0'` for null character.

```
std::replace (s.begin(), s.end(), 'l', '\0');
```

Since you are new to programming, I would tell you that it is better(a good practice) to use the namespace name along with the function rather than having `using namespace std` in your code.

Considering the comment from @mindriot fro this answer, I prefer to give another solution:

```
 s.erase( std::remove( s.begin(), s.end(), 'l' ), s.end() ) ;
```

You can also have a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20326356/how-to-remove-all-the-occurrences-of-a-char-in-c-string) for other related options.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but I agree with the downvote: Your answer does not remove all occurrences of `'1'`, but _replaces_ them with a `'\0'`. That's not the same. It turns `"123123"` into `"\00023\00023"`, which is not the same as the desired `"2323"`. Also, adding NUL characters may break if there is other code expecting a NUL-terminated string. E.g., try sending it to `std::cout`.

Comment: @mindriot: I agree with your second point. But nothing like that is mentioned in question.

Comment: @mindriot so what does the null character do then??