# Remove last occurrence of duplicate character in string

Tags: c++, c++17

how can i delete the rest of the characters?

```
s.erase(std::unique(s.begin(), s.end()), s.end());
```

This only deletes the duplicated characters and doesn't remove the first presence of the character.
Example: `"Hello World"`
would return `"he wrd"`

Answer (score 2):

There's no builtin for this function, but you can write your own generic algorithm to accomplish this:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

template <class C>
auto erase_if_duplicate(C& c)
{
    using T = typename C::value_type;

    const auto begin = c.begin();
    const auto end   = c.end();
    std::unordered_map<T, std::size_t> count{};

    std::for_each(
        begin, end,
        [&] (const T& v) { ++count[v]; });

    const auto it = std::remove_if(
        begin, end,
        [&] (const T& v) { return count.at(v) > 1; });

    return c.erase(it, end);
}

int main()
{
    // example usage
    std::string s{"hello world"};
    erase_if_duplicate(s);
    std::cout << s; // he wrd
}
```

[Try it on godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/z/nbMxdKzdK)

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want to [remove all occurrences of a character from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20326356/how-to-remove-all-the-occurrences-of-a-char-in-c-string) if it has duplicates (its count is bigger than `2`), and the removal is not case-sensitive (meaning `H` will be treated as `h`).

So, you can create a frequency map of all character, and if its count is `>1` then remove all of its occurrences with `erase()`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string x; getline(cin, x);
    map<char, int> freq;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < x.size(); i++)
    {
        x[i] = tolower(x[i]); //lowercase all the character
        freq[x[i]]++; //frequency of character
    }

    x.erase(remove_if(x.begin(), x.end(), 
            [&] (const char& c) { return freq[c] > 1; }), 
            x.end());
    cout << x;
}
```

Output :

```
Hello world
he wrd
```

Another example:

```
ABbcDdDEfF
ace
```

Comment: Please stop [using namespace `std`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).