# How to remove white space in the beginning of a sentence.

Tags: c++, string, vector

I made a vector that stores each sentence from a file. However, I noticed that each vector is stored differently. For example, if the file was "hello bob. how are you. hey there."

I used

```
while(getline(mFile, str, '.'))
```

to get each sentence and

```
vecString.push_back(str + '.');
```

to store each each sentence in the vector. So vector[0] would hold "hello bob.", vector[1] would hold " how are you.", and vector [3] would hold " hey there.". How do I get rid of the space in starting sentence of vector[2] and vector [3]?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the best way to trim std::string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216823/whats-the-best-way-to-trim-stdstring)

Answer (score 1):

The Boost String Algorithms Library has [trimming functions](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/string_algo/usage.html#idp206822440).

Answer (score 1):

There are many examples of this on stackoverflow.  Have a look at these.

[Removing leading and trailing spaces from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798112/removing-leading-and-trailing-spaces-from-a-string)

[What's the best way to trim std::string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216823/whats-the-best-way-to-trim-stdstring)

Answer (score 1):

Strip leading (i.e. left) whitespace using:

```
std::string s("  String with leading whitespace.");
s.erase(0, s.find_first_not_of(" \t"));
```

In addition to ' ' and '\t' consider also '\r', '\n', '\v', and '\f'.