# How to remove the leading white spaces but keep middle spaces in C++ `ifstream`?

Tags: c++, character-encoding, io, iostream, fstream

For example, I have a file with the following contents:

```
     Hello John Smith
               Hello Jack Brown
                     OK I love you
```

Note that each sentence has some leading white spaces. I want to use `std::fstream` to read them line by line, and want to remove the leading white spaces but keep the spaces between the words in a sentence.

My desired output should be as follows:

```
Hello John Smith
Hello Jack Brown
OK I love you
```

I also find [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798112/removing-leading-and-trailing-spaces-from-a-string?rq=1) gives many trivial methods to my question. However, I think none of them is elegant in terms of modern C++. Is there any more elegant means?

Answer (score 4):

```
std::ifstream file("input.txt");

std::string line;

while(std::getline(file,line))
{
     auto isspace = [](unsigned char ch) { return std::isspace(ch); };

     //find the first non-space character
     auto it = std::find_if_not(line.begin(), line.end(), isspace);

     line.erase(line.begin(), it); //erase all till the first non-space

     std::cout << line << "\n";
}
```

Note that we could just pass `std::isspace` as third argument to `std::find_if_not`, but there are [overloads of `std::isspace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/isspace) which causes compilation error — to fix this you can use cast though, as:

```
auto it = std::find_if_not(line.begin(), 
                           line.end(), 
                           static_cast<int(*)(int)>(std::isspace));
```

which looks ugly. But because of the function type in the cast, the compiler is able to figure out [which overload](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isspace) you intend to use in the code.

Comment: Several comments: first, you have undefined behavior.  You cannot call the one argument version of `isspace` with a `char`.  You should declare the lambda to take an `unsigned char` (or use `std::ctype<char>`; a bit trickier, but it allows you to use a specific locale without modifying the global locale).  Second, why not just specify the lambda as the third argument of `find_if` (and I'd specify the lambda so that `std::find_if` worked).  And finally: it's probably worth pointing out that this won't work for multi-byte characters, which are becoming more and more common.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Thanks for your comment. I used `std::find_if_not` just to demonstrate its usage and also I wanted to point out we could pass `std::isspace` as third argument (after casting).

Comment: But it's a C++11 function; if you use `std::find_if`, then you don't need C++11.  (Of course, you can't use lambda anyway, but you'll probably want to provide a global `IsSpace` and `NotIsSpace` predicate anyway, unless this is the only time you'll ever be processing text.)

Comment: And of course, while you _can_ pass `std::isspace` directly, it
will result in undefined behavior, since `std::find_if_not` will
end up passing it a `char`.  (For historical reasons, character
processing in C++ is more complex than it should be, and has
a number of sneaky traps.  Back when I was doing it a lot, one
of my test inputs was always a list of Paris suburbs.  With
`"L'Haÿ-les-Roses"`.  You'd be surprised at how many programs
stopped at the `'ÿ'`.  Character code 255 in Latin-1.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: Great comments. Hope viewers of this answer read your comments as well.

Answer (score 4):

As a complement to Nawaz' answer: it's worth pointing out that
Boost has a String_Algo library, with (along with a lot of other
things) functions like `trim`, which will simplify the code
a lot.  If you're doing any text processing at all, and you
can't or don't want to use Boost, you should implement something
similar yourself for your toolkit (e.g. a function
MyUtils::trim, based on Nawaz' algorithms).

Finally, if you may need someday to handle UTF-8 input, then you
should look into ICU.