# C++ white space string

Tags: c++

I'm brand new into C++. I would like to know, why my code is not working.
I've got string called Response. 
If the response begins with y/Y it should proceed. However I would like to proceed when the user types " y"/" Y" (the white space) as well.
Here is my code. 
Thanks in advance!

```
bool AskToPlayAgain()
{
    std::cout << "Would you like to play again? Yes/N";
    std::string Response = "";
    std::getline(std::cin, Response);
    return (Response[0] == 'y') || (Response[0] == 'Y' +) ||(Response[0] == ' y' +) (Response[0] == ' Y' +); 
    std::cout << std::endl;


}
```

Comment: Try to `trim` the response and then check the first character. Furthermore, your statement `std::cout << std::endl;` is unreachable

Comment: `''` is used for a single char literal. You can't use it for a string like ` y`. For strings, `""` should be used. But then, you can't compare string with the first char of response. I suggest looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83439/remove-spaces-from-stdstring-in-c) to remove whitespaces first and then compare your string to somethign.

Comment: I would trim the string to remove whitespace (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798112/removing-leading-and-trailing-spaces-from-a-string) and use [std::tolower](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/tolower) to make the input lowercase and then perform a single check for `'y'`.

Comment: The code you've posted doesn't even compile. Try putting together a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `Response[0]` you access the first character of the string. You can compare that, as you do, with a character constant, such as `'y'`. However, if you want to allow the leading space, this is no longer a single character, so your comparison `Response[0] == ' y'` cannot work.

Here is a version which allows as many space characters as needed, and then y or Y (C++11 version):

```
for (auto c:Response)
    if (c!=' ')
        return (c=='y') || (c=='Y');

 //string is only spaces
 return false;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can traverse string `Response` and ignore white spaces(I am considering `Tabs` and `Spaces` in this case) while traversing.
If first character is non white space then you can break the loop I am using flag `yes` in this case.

```
bool AskToPlayAgain()
{
    std::cout << "Would you like to play again? Yes/N";
    auto Response="";
    std::getline(std::cin, Response);
    auto yes = false;
    auto itr = Response.begin();
    while(itr != Response.end())
    {
        if(*itr != ' ' && *itr !='\t')
        {
            yes = (*itr == 'y' || *itr =='Y') ;
            break;
        }
        ++itr;
    }
    return yes; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Use a loop to check each of your character inside the input string...

For example, like this, usage of the usual loop which can be used in all versions of C++ (***You can use the [range based for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) like in the above answer...***):

```
bool ask_to_play_again(std::string Response)
{
    for (auto i = 0; i < Response.size(); i++)
        if (!isspace(Response[i])) // Is not a whitespace character
            return tolower(Response[i]) == 'y';
    return false; // If the user enters invalid input, close the game anyway...
}
```

Kind regards,

Ruks.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the spaces from the response and check with only 'Y'/'y'.

```
bool AskToPlayAgain()  
{  
    std::cout << "Would you like to play again? Yes/N";  
    std::string Response = "";  
    std::getline(std::cin, Response);  
    Response.erase(remove(Response.begin(), Response.end(), ' '), Response.end()); 
    return (Response[0] == 'y') || (Response[0] == 'Y'); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use std::find function to resolve the problem.

```
bool AskToPlayAgain()
{
    std::cout << "Would you like to play again? Yes/N";
    std::string Response = "";
    std::getline(std::cin, Response);
    auto pos1 = Response.find("Y");
    auto pos2 = Response.find("y");
    if (pos1 != std::string::npos || pos2 != std::string::npos)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: this will also return `true` if the user enters "no I dont want to play again" ;)